mysql not starting on ubuntu server 20.04
I am running Ubuntu server 20.04 in a Truenas Scale Virtual Machine. It has:

5GiB Ram
1 Virtual CPU
2 Cores
100 GiB Storage  

I am connected to it with SSH and installed MYSQL with:  sudo apt isntall mysql-server -y  which gave me a result of:
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  galera-4 libconfig-inifiles-perl libdbd-mariadb-perl libdbi-perl libmariadb3 libmysqlclient21 libterm-readkey-perl mariadb-common pv socat
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  mysql-server
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 9,480 B of archives.
After this operation, 35.8 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 mysql-server all 8.0.39-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 [9,480 B]
Fetched 9,480 B in 0s (228 kB/s)         
N: Ignoring file 'mariadb.list.old_1' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
Selecting previously unselected package mysql-server.
(Reading database ... 73901 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../mysql-server_8.0.39-0ubuntu0.20.04.1_all.deb ...
Unpacking mysql-server (8.0.39-0ubuntu0.20.04.1) ...
Setting up mysql-server (8.0.39-0ubuntu0.20.04.1) ...
N: Ignoring file 'mariadb.list.old_1' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension

I then tried to start the service with: sudo systemctl start mysql.service
 which gave me a result of:
Job for mysql.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status mysql.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.

further logs: https://pastebin.com/NH3U183M
The results of journalctl -xe are:
Aug 17 20:00:21 truenas-vm1 systemd[1]: mysql.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
-- Subject: Unit failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- The unit mysql.service has entered the 'failed' state with result 'exit-code'.
Aug 17 20:00:21 truenas-vm1 systemd[1]: Failed to start MySQL Community Server.
-- Subject: A start job for unit mysql.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- A start job for unit mysql.service has finished with a failure.
-- 
-- The job identifier is 14093 and the job result is failed.
Aug 17 20:00:21 truenas-vm1 systemd[1]: mysql.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 5.
-- Subject: Automatic restarting of a unit has been scheduled
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- Automatic restarting of the unit mysql.service has been scheduled, as the result for
-- the configured Restart= setting for the unit.
Aug 17 20:00:21 truenas-vm1 systemd[1]: Stopped MySQL Community Server.
-- Subject: A stop job for unit mysql.service has finished
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- A stop job for unit mysql.service has finished.
-- 
-- The job identifier is 14192 and the job result is done.
Aug 17 20:00:21 truenas-vm1 systemd[1]: mysql.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Aug 17 20:00:21 truenas-vm1 systemd[1]: mysql.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
-- Subject: Unit failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- The unit mysql.service has entered the 'failed' state with result 'exit-code'.
Aug 17 20:00:21 truenas-vm1 systemd[1]: Failed to start MySQL Community Server.
-- Subject: A start job for unit mysql.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- A start job for unit mysql.service has finished with a failure.
-- 
-- The job identifier is 14192 and the job result is failed.

and systemctl status mysql.service is:
mysql.service - MySQL Community Server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mysql.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sat 2024-08-17 20:00:21 UTC; 12min ago
    Process: 38509 ExecStartPre=/usr/share/mysql/mysql-systemd-start pre (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 
Aug 17 20:00:21 truenas-vm1 systemd[1]: mysql.service: Control process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Aug 17 20:00:21 truenas-vm1 systemd[1]: mysql.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Aug 17 20:00:21 truenas-vm1 systemd[1]: Failed to start MySQL Community Server.
Aug 17 20:00:21 truenas-vm1 systemd[1]: mysql.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 5.
Aug 17 20:00:21 truenas-vm1 systemd[1]: Stopped MySQL Community Server.
Aug 17 20:00:21 truenas-vm1 systemd[1]: mysql.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Aug 17 20:00:21 truenas-vm1 systemd[1]: mysql.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Aug 17 20:00:21 truenas-vm1 systemd[1]: Failed to start MySQL Community Server.


Can you add the logs on https://pastebin.com/ and provide the link to the paste?

@Kulfy done https://pastebin.com/NH3U183M

The systemctl status output seems to indicate that the failure occurs in the ExecStartPre command (/usr/share/mysql/mysql-systemd-start pre) which is a script that does some sanity checks on the configuration and data dirs. The apt message about an ignored mariadb.list.old_1 makes me wonder if you had a previous mariadb installation that is perhaps breaking one of these checks?

yeah, i did have it installed but did uninstall it before trying to install mysql. i'll try deleting that file.
